# URL check only works on second time within iframe

Tags: javascript, string, iframe

I currently use

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("Startseiteplayerrun") > -1) {
      alert("You have the player open already !");
      window.history.back();
    } else {
  //window.open("Startseiteplayerrun.html","_self");
  link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = "Startseiteplayerrun.html";
  //link.target = "_blank";
  link.click()
;}});
</script><br>
<a href="index.html">home</a>
```

to check whether the string "Startseiteplayerrun" is present in the url bar.

However,
this check only seems to happen after failing the first time
=> I'm able to open the frame once within itself:

[image: frame can be opened once b4 script properly recognizes url string and]

Can this be mitigated ?
The purposeof this "if else" is to *not* allow another iframe,
if the urlbar contains "Startseiteplayerrun" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string won't check right away, check if framed
~FIN~

```
<script>
if ( window.location !== window.parent.location ) {
alert("You have the player open already !"); 
window.history.back(); 
 } else {
// The page is not in an iframe
}
</script>
```